# How to define document in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

I am using brackets editor for code editing. I have already installed a brackets extension "js lint". For DOM element I have to write `document.getElemenstById` or other DOM syntax. JS lint shows an error "document is not defined". So please tell me what is the syntax for define document in JS?

Comment: "Assume a browser?" https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch78U.png

Comment: `document` is something provided by the browser runtime environment, so unless your linter has a mode that accounts for that it won't be defined.

Comment: In addition to @tadman above, it's `document.getElementById`, not `document.getElemenstById` because `id`s should be unique within a document, so you should never find two with the same `id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is a language with its own syntax and built in types. `document` is not defined in the JavaScript (also more formally known as ECMAScript) **[specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)**. `document` is provided as an object API by the JavaScript "host" environment, which in a web page scenario, is the user agent (also known as the browser). Modern browser's supply a wide range of objects to the JavaScript runtime and your linter is not likely to advise you about them. However, there is a standard for the `document` API called the **[Document Object Model](https://www.w3.org/DOM/)**, which is maintained by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C), who sets many standards for the web.

To make a little more sense out of this, there is a very popular server-side application called Node JS. Node contains a full JavaScript runtime that conforms to the ECMAScript standard. But Node is a command line, server-side application, not a browser. You don't execute web pages in Node, so there would never be a need for a `document` object. Thankfully, JavaScript doesn't define a `document` object, so all is well.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to remove all the JS Lint markers for "document is not defined" is to put "var document;" at the top of your JS file, just so you can see more clearly what the real errors are.

Do not leave "var document;" within the JS file though as it can cause problems.

I hope that makes things easier for you.